# Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have a problem with artisan and the migrations.

I just created a new project, copy-paste my database using `Laravel Schema Design`, put the `schemaLenght` into my `config/database.php` file. Then I made the php artisan migrate and I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = table_atelier and table_name = migrations).

So, I would like to know, what is the problem?

I think, maybe it's the new version of MAMP, I upgrad it. Or, maybe, the php version (I have the `7.1.12` or the `7.2.1`).

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your credentials.
Did you use the right credentials in your .env?

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=My table
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

Comment: Your database is called "My table" ?

Comment: table_atelier  is the name of your database or the table?

DB_DATABASE= 
should contain the name of your database

Comment: I have DB_DATABASE=table_atelier ; it's the name of my database in mysql.

Comment: So you changed it? now run
`php artisan config:cache`
and try again.

Comment: ' Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = table_atelier and table_name = migrations)'.
I try it and i have this notification.

Comment: are you using mac?
Often you need to set you unix socket in .env
`DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`
When you've done this check if your config/database.php has the following line in 'mysql'
            `'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '')`,

Comment: i have the line in my database file but i don't have the DB_SOCKET in my .env . I'm going to try

Answer (score 0):

That because NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER (sql-mode) has removed in mysql 8, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-removals

The file has modified by creator of Laravel [formmating commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faXHc.png)

```
return "set session sql_mode='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'";
```